# How to append customer context-menuitem to the last postion in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I'm running on `Ubuntu 12.04`.
I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions) to add `Quit` to `firefox`'s right-click context-menu.
`Firebug` also add a context-menuitem(`Inspect Element with Firebug`) to the last.
The result is not what I want.

---

This command give me empty result:

```
grep -r 'Inspect Element with Firebug' .
```

So I don't know how `firebug` create the menuitem.
But I can edit `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/chrome/userChrome.css` to hide it:

```
menuitem[label="Inspect Element with Firebug"] {
    display:none;
}
```

---

### What I did:

```
cd ~

pkill firefox

cp /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja ~

unzip omni.ja -d omni

cd omni

find . -name 'browser.xul'

vi ./chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.xul    
    {{{
    <menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu" ...
        <menuitem id="context-inspect" ...

        <!-- QUIT BEGIN -->
        <menuitem id="context-quit"
                      label="Quit"
                      command="cmd_quitApplication"/>
        <!-- QUIT END -->
    </menupopup>
    }}}

zip -r omni.ja *

sudo mv omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/

firefox http://www.google.com
```

### What I get:

```
| ...                          |
| View Page Info               |
|------------------------------|
| Inspect Element(Q)           |
| Quit                         |
|------------------------------|
| Inspect Element with Firebug |
+------------------------------+
```

### What I want:

```
| ...                          |
| View Page Info               |
|------------------------------|
| Inspect Element(Q)           |
| Inspect Element with Firebug |
|------------------------------|
| Quit                         |
+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. unzip `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi`
2. edit `firebug/content/firebug/firefox/browserMenuOverlay.xul`
3. zip and replace

### original

```
<!-- Firefox page context menu -->
<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menuseparator/>
    <menuitem id="menu_firebugInspect" label="firebug.InspectElementWithFirebug"
              command="cmd_inspect" class="menuitem-iconic fbInternational"/>
</menupopup>
```

---

### modified

```
<!-- Firefox page context menu -->
<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menuitem id="menu_firebugInspect" label="firebug.InspectElementWithFirebug"
              command="cmd_inspect" class="menuitem-iconic fbInternational"
              insertafter="context-inspect" />
</menupopup>
```