# How to add a [Proxy ON/OFF] context-menuitem to firefox?

Tags: firefox

I've known [how to add context-menuitem to firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/421800/how-to-append-customer-context-menuitem-to-the-last-postion-in-firefox).

I frequently toggle <kbd>Edit</kbd>-><kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Advanced</kbd>-><kbd>Network</kbd>-><kbd>No Proxy | Manual proxy configuration</kbd>

I want to add a <kbd>Proxy ON/OFF</kbd> to context-menu, it'll help me a lot.
I don't want to install another add-on to do this tiny job.
Is there a quick way? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to install the excellent [Toggle Proxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggle-proxy-51740/) add-on (which gives you a keyboard shortcut and a toolbar button), you can go to the special URL `about:config` and change the value of `network.proxy.type` according to [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.type#Possible_values_and_their_effects):

- `0` - Direct connection, no proxy
- `1` - Manual proxy configuration
- `2` - Proxy auto-configuration (PAC)
- `4` - Auto-detect proxy settings
- `5` - Use system proxy settings (default on all platforms)

Specifically, it sounds like you will be toggling between `5` and `0`.

Answer (score 1):

As what I did in [how to add context-menuitem to firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/421800/how-to-append-customer-context-menuitem-to-the-last-postion-in-firefox).
I've added <kbd>Toggle Proxy</kbd>:

```
<!-- TOGGLE-PROXY BEGIN -->
      <menuitem id="context-toggle-proxy"
                label="Toggle Proxy"
                oncommand="gPrefService.setIntPref('network.proxy.type', !gPrefService.getIntPref('network.proxy.type'));"/>
<!-- TOGGLE-PROXY END -->
```

Currently, I'm working on how to display <kbd>Proxy ON</kbd>/<kbd>Proxy OFF</kbd> depending on current proxy setting.
If you have any idea, please let me known.

#### Caution:

You should enable/disable an add-on to reload `omni.ja`.
Because I've wasted one hour on this.

Comment: Note that `!gPrefService.getIntPref('network.proxy.type')` will toggle Boolean values, which probably get cast to `0` and `1`. It's probably better to use `(gPrefService.getIntPref('network.proxy.type') == 0) ? 1 : 0`, the [ternary operator](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/ternary.php). The `1` you should use to specify the type when proxy is on, as in [Alex's answer](http://superuser.com/a/421814/117590).